# I don't understand the output of the expr command

Tags: bash, scripts

When I run this code

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
str="I am enjoying this day to the fullest !"
x="this"
y=`expr index "$str" "$x"`
z=${str:`expr $y - 1`:5}
echo $x
echo $y
echo $z
```

the output is this

```
this
11
ing t
```

so I want to know why this is so.
And how can I fix this?

Comment: What output did you expect ? What is the problem ?

Comment: Did you look at the man expr page?  "any chars" in pattern, "i" in this is found at position 11, as documented.

Comment: the output should be this at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index searches for characters.  Perhaps you wanted match?

Try

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
str="I am enjoying this day to the fullest !"
x="this"
y=$(expr  "$str" : ".*$x" - length "$x")
z=${str:$y:${#x}}
echo $x
echo $y
echo $z
```

The : operator is the anchored regex match operator.
The pattern to match is "." (any character) "*" zero or more of them, followed by the string in $x (note: this should not contain unescaped regex characters)

This portion will return the length of the matched strong, which will be the number of characters from the beginning of the string ("anchored") to the end of the string in $x.

The next portion subtracts the length of $x to result in the offset in $str to the first character of $x.  This could be replaced with ${#x} as in the following line.

Comment: `y=$(expr  "$str" : ".*$x" - length "$x")`  can you please explain this command.